# Golang сравнить слайсы байт, полученные из 16-ричных строк

Tags: golang

Хочу переписать вот такой код с си на го:

```
static void GOST_Kuz_X(const uint8_t *a, const uint8_t *b, uint8_t *c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
}
```

Не понимаю, на что заменить указатели на массивы байт. У меня получается такой код:

```
package main

const BlockSize = 16

func GostX(a, b, c []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < BlockSize; i++ {
        c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i]
    }
}
```

И такой юнит-тест:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "testing"
)

func TestGostX(t *testing.T) {
    c, _ := hex.DecodeString("6ea276726c487ab85d27bd10dd849401")
    k, _ := hex.DecodeString("8899aabbccddeeff0011223344556677")
    expected, _ := hex.DecodeString("e63bdcc9a09594475d369f2399d1f276")

    var result []byte
    GostX(c, k, result)
    if result != expected {
        t.Errorf("GostX was incorrect, got %x, want %x.", result, expected)
    }
}
```

При запуске теста получаю ошибку:

```
# gost
./gost_test.go:15:12: invalid operation: result != expected (slice can only be compared to nil)
FAIL    gost [build failed]
```

Как я понял из гугла, в голанге вместо указателей на массивы используются слайсы. Аргументы типа слайса можно изменять внутри функции. Но здесь у меня проблема: `hex.DecodeString` возвращает слайс, и при сравнении слайсов я получаю ошибку, потому что слайсы можно сравнивать только с nil. Что делать? Если надо преобразовать слайс в массив, то как это делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`bytes.Equal`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal):

> ```
>  func Equal(a, b []byte) bool
> ```
>
> Equal returns a boolean reporting whether a and b are the same length and contain the same bytes. A nil argument is equivalent to an empty slice.

Либо, если хотите что-то общее для большинства типов, [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).